# Add border above/below element causing parent to overflow

Tags: html, css, border

I have something like this:

```css
div.parent {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
}
div.parent div.thing {
  height: 20px;
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
</div>
```

[image: thing]
How can I have a border where the things disappear (in this case, above the top "something")?

Comment: You could add a flex display to the parent and set its direction to column and this would fix the overflow landing in the middle of the last visible element, is this what you're after?

Comment: @dalelandry That looks the same as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your scrolled elements in another DIV. Create a **border** *looking* element height 1px, width same as children elements. Then set its position to ***sticky*** and its parents position to ***relative*** so it will stick to the top of the scroll-able parent element. This will give you a top border on the children elements.

```css
div.grand-parent {
  padding: 20px;
}

div.parent {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.border-top {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: calc(90% + 2px);
  height: 1px;
  background-color: black;
}

div.parent div.thing {
  height: 20px;
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grand-parent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="border-top"></div>
    <div class="thing">something</div>
    <div class="thing">something</div>
    <div class="thing">something</div>
    <div class="thing">something</div>
    <div class="thing">something</div>
    <div class="thing">something</div>
    <div class="thing">something</div>
    <div class="thing">something</div>
    <div class="thing">something</div>
    <div class="thing">something</div>
    <div class="thing">something</div>
    <div class="thing">something</div>
    <div class="thing">something</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***EDIT:*** OP asking to add a full border with radius around entire section. I know this is not exactly what the OP is looking for in their comment, but it is as close as I can get.

This *may possibly* be achieved using an SVG clip-path perhaps in conjunction with something like what I have coded below or a radial gradient perhaps.

Basically I removed the borders on your single child elements and added a pseudo element to create a border like element relatively placed on top of each child element, giving the illusion of a top and bottom border. I wrapped the entire parent element in the same absolutely positioned element. I just added x axis padding and then gave it a top and bottom border with a 1rem radius. Then I added two pseudo elements and set them as `position: sticky`, these are placed relative to the top/left and top/right positions of the parent element. I added a black background to these and calculated width to include relevant properties of calculated widths.

```css
div.grand-parent {
  padding: 20px;
}

div.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 1.1rem;
}

div.border-left {
  position: fixed;
  left: 28px;
  top: 28px;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
}

div.border-right {
  position: fixed;
  left: calc(80% - 1rem);
  width: 1rem;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;
}

.border-top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 28px;
  left: 28px;
  width: calc(80% - 2rem);
  height: 100px;
  border-top: black 1px solid;  
  border-bottom: black 1px solid;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background-color: transparent;
}

div.parent div.thing {
  height: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

div.parent div.thing:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="grand-parent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="border-top"></div>
    <div class="border-left"></div>    
    <div class="border-right"></div>
    <div class="thing">something</div>
    <div class="thing">something</div>
    <div class="thing">something</div>
    <div class="thing">something</div>
    <div class="thing">something</div>
    <div class="thing">something</div>
    <div class="thing">something</div>
    <div class="thing">something</div>
    <div class="thing">something</div>
    <div class="thing">something</div>
    <div class="thing">something</div>
    <div class="thing">something</div>
    <div class="thing">something</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to give everything a `border-radius`?

Comment: @illogicalapple that's a tough one for sure, using positioned elements as they are. as the child elements borders will *bleed* out of the top and bottom radius'. You may want to look into a clip path for that one. I have however included the closest I could achieve at a radius border all the way around the children elements.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: I just added **border-bottom** property to parent class

```css
div.parent {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
div.parent div.thing {
  height: 20px;
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't look too great: it applies a border to the entire outer element.

Answer (score 0):

sticky pseudo elements can do it:

```css
div.parent {
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
}
div.parent div.thing {
  height: 20px;
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.parent:before,
div.parent:after {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width: calc(90% + 2px);
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  height:1px;
  margin:-1px 0;
  background:black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
  <div class="thing">something</div>
</div>
```